# UML sequence diagram, call

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram, visual-paradigm

Let's say we have three classes `A, B` and `C`, and an instance `a` (resp. `b`/`c`) of type `A` (resp. `B`/`C`).
Suppose that `b` is an attribute of `a` and `c` is an attribute of `b`.

In a method of `a`, the following is called : `b.c.operation()`

How can we represent this  in a sequence diagram ?

Comment: Have a try at it yourself first

Comment: I don't know if I need to have 1) one arrow from a to c 2) one arrow from b to c 3) one arrow from a to b and one from b to c...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter), an object should only communicate directly with its own *neighbours*. So in your case, a should not be calling b.c.operation() at all, as c is not a's *neighbour*. Rather, class B should provide an interface for this purpose, such as
`doCOperation(){c.operation();}`
and this is what a should call.

So the sequence of operations beocomes:

1. a calls `b.doCOperation()`
2. b calls `c.Operation()` within `doCOperation()` and returns the result to a.

Have a go at the sequence diagram now and it should be much easier.

Comment: I never knew that this is called LoD (after doing that stuff for >30 years), but only under the term "information hiding".

Answer (score 1):

In programming it is not good to have `b.c.operation()`

> All data should be hidden (should be private) in the class.

But if we have `b.c.operation()` , in the compiler it changes to `(b.c).operation()`
so your code is equal to this code:

```
t=b.c;
t.operation();
```

Comment: the compiler changes it? or at Runtime?

Comment: absolutely compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Is this something you are looking for? You can try it out at https://www.zenuml.com.

[image]